# spark 1.5.2 - Programmatically launching spark on yarn-client mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

we were using spark 1.3.1 and launching our spark jobs on yarn-client mode programmatically via creating a sparkConf and sparkContext object manually. It was inspired from spark self-contained application example here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications\

Only additional configuration we would provide would be all related to yarn like executor instance, cores etc.

However after upgrading to spark 1.5.2 above application breaks on a line `val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)`

It throws following in driver application:

```
16/01/28 17:38:35 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main

java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:152)

at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1228)

at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:100)

at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1749)

at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1185)

at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1748)

at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:593)
```

So is this approach still supposed to work? Or do I must use `SparkLauncher` class with spark 1.5.2 to launch spark job programmatically on yarn-client mode?

Comment: I got this working by submitting job via spark-oozie action from Oozie 4.1.0. It does require some work on oozie installation to put correct jars but ufff I am able to submit job again with happily loaded SparkContext from my application class. No need of using buggy and undocumented SparkLauncher for now :)